# Value in MudBlazor table does not change

Tags: c#, blazor

I need to change the value of a particular column in a blazor MudTable. The way I edit it is, as soon as the user inputs a value, the total changes. Please see the codes below on how I do it:

**HTML**

```
<MudTable Items="@Elements.Take(9)" Hover="true" Breakpoint="Breakpoint.Sm" @ref="mudTable" RowClassFunc="@SelectedRowClassFunc" OnRowClick="RowClickEvent" T="Element">
    <RowTemplate>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Cash Value">
            <input class="table-input" @oninput="@((e) => { doTheMath(@context, e); })" type="text" value="@context.CashValue"/>
        </MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Cash Amount" Style="text-align:center; width: 100px;">@context.CashAmount</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Total">
            <input type="text" class="table-input" value="@context.Total" disabled/>
        </MudTd>
    </RowTemplate>
</MudTable>



private IEnumerable<Element> Elements = new List<Element>()
    {
       new Element() { CashValue="0", CashAmount = "x 1000", Total = "0"},
       new Element() { CashValue="0", CashAmount = "x 500", Total = "0"},
       new Element() { CashValue="0", CashAmount = "x 200", Total = "0"},
       new Element() { CashValue="0", CashAmount = "x 100", Total = "0"},
       new Element() { CashValue="0", CashAmount = "x 50", Total = "0"},
       new Element() { CashValue="0", CashAmount = "x 20", Total = "0"},
       new Element() { CashValue="0", CashAmount = "x 10", Total = "0"},
       new Element() { CashValue="0", CashAmount = "x 5", Total = "0"},
       new Element() { CashValue="0", CashAmount = "x 1", Total = "0"},
    };

private void doTheMath(Element element, ChangeEventArgs c)
    {
        try
        {
            var selectedElement = Elements.Where(x => x.CashAmount.Equals(element.CashAmount)).First();
            var cashAmount = selectedElement.CashAmount.Replace("x", "").Trim();
            var x = int.Parse(c.Value.ToString());
            var y = int.Parse(cashAmount);
            selectedElement.Total = (x * y).ToString("###,###.00");
            selectedElement.CashValue = c.Value.ToString();
            StateHasChanged();
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
       
    }
```

I can actually complete the whole method of "doTheMath()" but my table does not update according to the edited values.

Comment: Can you add your part of razor page?

Comment: The upper part my question is the razor page.

Comment: How do you know that `doTheMath` completes correctly?